# Solving a LP problem

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, duality-theorems

I am learning optimization and I came across this exercise to solve the following problem:

$$\min 2x_1+3x_2$$

$$x_1+x_2\geq 5$$

$$x_1\geq 1$$

$$x_2\geq 2$$

This exercise has been introduced just after the definition of the standard LP and the corresponding dual problem. 
The question is to prove that $x^*=(3,2)$ is the optimal solution by showing that the objective value of any feasible solution is at least 12.

I have tried to convert the problem to the dual form.

First I convert my LP problem to a *standard* LP problem by introducing the surplus variables $x_3,x_4,x_5:$

$$\min 2x_1+3x_2$$

$$x_1+x_2-x_3 = 5$$

$$x_1-x_4 = 1$$

$$x_2 - x_5 = 2$$

with all $x_i \geq 0$.

Then I convert the problem to the corresponding standard dual:

$$\max 5y_1+y_2+2y_3$$

$$y_1+y_2\leq 2$$

$$y_3\leq 3$$

$$y_i \geq 0, i \in \{1,2,3\}$$

But then I am stuck...

Comment: How can $x^*=(3,2)$ if $x_1\geq5$?  Did you mean to write $x_1\geq3$?

Comment: You are right, sorry for the typo. I have corrected it. Thanks

Comment: @JejeBelfort Note the constraints at the dual are $$y_1+y_2\color{red}= 2$$

$$y_3\color{red}= 3$$

Comment: Assuming that you're thinking of your primal as including the implicit (but redundant) constraints $\ x_1 \ge 0\ ,$ and $\  x_2\ge 0\  $ , then the second inequality in your dual, corresponding to the variable $\ x_2\ $ of the primal, should be $y_1 + y_3 \le 3\ $, because the coefficient of $\ x_2\ $ in the first inequality of the primal, corresponding to the variable $\ y_1\ $ of the dual, is $\ 1\ $.

Comment: @JejeBelfort Your dual is still wrong. Didn´t you get my comment?

Comment: @callculus yes I did, but this is not what is presented in the lecture notes. Inequalities become equalities when introducing the surplus/slack variables.

Comment: @JejeBelfort The rule is the following: If the variables are **free** (unconstrained) at the primal(dual) then the corresponding constraints are **equalities** at the dual(primal).

Comment: @JejeBelfort I cannot wait anymore for a reply from you. But improve your dual program.

Answer (score 1):

**Edited hint:** Since a reformulation of the original problem into standard form has now been added, my original answer is no longer very comprehensible.  The dual of the problem, as originally formulated is:

$
\begin{eqnarray}
 \max 5y_1\ + &y_2&+\ 2y_3\\
\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \mbox{  subject to:} & &\\
y_1+y_2\ \ \ &=& 2\\
y_1 + \ \ \   y_3&=&3\ \mbox{, and}\\
y_1\ge0, y_2&\ge0,& y_3\ge 0
\end{eqnarray}
$

As [callculus](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/144421/callculus) has pointed out, in the absence of any *explicit* sign restrictions on the variabes $x_1, \mbox{and } x_2\ $, the constraints in the dual should be *equations* rather than inequalities.  However, since the second and third constraints of the primal imply that $\ x_1\ge0, \mbox{and } x_2\ge0\ $, these *implied* constraints *could* have been made explicit in the original formulation—as you have now so made them in your reformulation into standard form—, and then the dual constraints would have been $y_1+y_2 \le 2\ $ and $y_1 +  y_3\le3\ $, as they are, in fact, for the standard form, whose dual is:

$
\begin{eqnarray}
 \max 5y_1\ + &y_2&+\ 2y_3\\
\ \ \ \ \ \mbox{  subject to:}& &\\
y_1+y_2\ \ \ &\le& 2\\
y_1 + \ \ \   y_3&\le&3\ \mbox{, and}\\
y_1\ge0, y_2&\ge0,& y_3\ge 0\ \ .
\end{eqnarray}
$

Now if $\ x^* = \left(3, 2\right)\ $ is an optimal solution for the primal, then because the non-negativity conditions, $\ x_1 \ge 0\ \mbox{ and } x_2 \ge0$, of your primal (in standard form) are both *slack* for those values (i.e. $\ 3\, {\color{red} >}\, 0\  \mbox{ and }\ 2\, {\color{red} >}\, 0 $), the *complementary slackness conditions* imply that the corresponding constraints, $\ y_1+y_2\le 2\ \mbox{ and } y_1 + y_3\le3\ $, must be *tight* for an  optimal solution, $\ \left(y_1^*, y_2^*, y_3^*\right)\ $, of the dual—that is, $\ y_1^*+y_2^*= 2\ \mbox{ and } y_1^* + y_3^*=3\ $.  Similarly, because the non-negativity condition $x_4 \ge 0$ is also slack (since $\ x_4 = x_1^* - 1 = 2\, {\color{red} >}\, 0\ $), then the corresponding constraint, $\ y_2 \ge 0\ $, should be tight for the optimal solution of the dual. That is, $\ y_2^* = 0\ $. These conditions are sufficient to determine uniquely what the optimal solution of the dual would have to be—namely, $\ y_1^* = 2, y_2^* = 0,\ $ and $\ y_3^* = 1\ $.  To verify that these purported optimal solutions really are optimal, all you have to do is check that the values of their respective objective functions are the same for both of them, which is, in fact, the case.

Comment: You haven´t mentioned that the dual is still wrong.

Comment: I was assuming that the primal constraints implicitly included the redundant inequalities $x_1\ge 0\ $ and $\ x_2\ge 0\ $, in which case the dual constraints can be inequalites rather than equations.

Comment: I´ve change my downvote into an upvote.

Comment: --------Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Let's use a graphical solution.
Taking $x_1$ on x axis and latter on y axis.
We get
$$x+y≥5$$
 $$x≥1$$
 $$y≥2$$
And we need to find the minimum value of c
In $$2x+3y= c$$[image of graphical rendering by desmos](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uBXVw.jpg)
By slowly increasing c we can easily see that it first intersects the red area (possible values of X and y) first at (2,3) and is the unique solution to c= 12
I have used a graphing calculator for this but it can be easily drawn on paper.

Comment: Agreed for the graphical solution, thanks! However, I don't think this is the philosophy of the exercise, which is to play around with the dual problem.

Comment: Welcome to MSE: It should be clear from the question that the person who asked it is *not* after a solution that uses computers.